# ASP.NET Error, GAC Corrupted

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, windows-7

I am developing ASP.NET web application (C#). When I rebuild my solution, the process very slow than before. And I got this error.

```
The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131018) 
  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

 Exception Details: System.BadImageFormatException: The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131018)

Source Error: 


 An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

Stack Trace: 



[BadImageFormatException: The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131018)]
   System.Reflection.Assembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, Assembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection) +0
   System.Reflection.Assembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, Assembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection) +43
   System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +127
   System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +142
   System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) +28
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +46

[ConfigurationErrorsException: The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131018)]
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +613
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo ai) +57
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig) +178
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler..ctor(VirtualPath configPath, Boolean supportLocalization, String outputAssemblyName) +54
   System.Web.Compilation.ApplicationBuildProvider.GetGlobalAsaxBuildResult(Boolean isPrecompiledApp) +232
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileGlobalAsax() +51
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled() +337

[HttpException (0x80004005): The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131018)]
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ReportTopLevelCompilationException() +58
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled() +512
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters) +729

[HttpException (0x80004005): The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131018)]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +8994307
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +85
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +333




Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.5485; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.5491
```

And all of my web application project on IIS get same errors. Its working fine before.
I am using Visual Studio 2008, .NET Framework 3.5, and develop on Windows 7 32bit.

I try uninstall .NET Framework 3.5 and reinstall it but get same error. Then try to using NetFxTools and still get same error. Anyone can help me please ?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions" type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
            <sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
                <section name="scriptResourceHandler" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                <sectionGroup name="webServices" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingWebServicesSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
                    <section name="jsonSerialization" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingJsonSerializationSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="Everywhere"/>
                    <section name="profileService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingProfileServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                    <section name="authenticationService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingAuthenticationServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                    <section name="roleService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingRoleServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                </sectionGroup>
            </sectionGroup>
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="CrystalImageCleaner-AutoStart" value="true"/>
        <add key="CrystalImageCleaner-Sleep" value="60000"/>
        <add key="CrystalImageCleaner-Age" value="120000"/>
    </appSettings>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="SQlID" connectionString="xxx"/>
        <add name="SQLPWD" connectionString="xxx"/>         
        <add name="Conn" connectionString="server=server;database=db;user id=xxx;pwd=xxxx;Connection Timeout=1440;Pooling=true;Min Pool Size=0;Max Pool Size=20;"/>
    </connectionStrings>
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime executionTimeout="120"/>
        <compilation debug="false" batch="false">
            <assemblies>

                <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
                <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
                <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
                <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
                <add assembly="DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors.v9.1, Version=9.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5377C8E3B72B4073"/>
                <add assembly="DevExpress.Web.v9.1, Version=9.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5377C8E3B72B4073"/>
                <add assembly="System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
                <add assembly="DevExpress.Data.v9.1, Version=9.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5377C8E3B72B4073"/>
                <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
                <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
                <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
                <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
                <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
                <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.VSDesigner, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
                <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Data.AdoDotNetInterop, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
                <add assembly="DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.v9.1.Export, Version=9.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5377C8E3B72B4073"/>
                <add assembly="DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.v9.1, Version=9.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5377C8E3B72B4073"/>
                <add assembly="DevExpress.XtraPrinting.v9.1, Version=9.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5377C8E3B72B4073"/>
                <add assembly="DevExpress.Utils.v9.1, Version=9.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5377C8E3B72B4073"/>
                <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportSource, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
                <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
                <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Framework, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
                <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.InfoStore, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
                <add assembly="DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors.v9.1, Version=9.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5377C8E3B72B4073"/>
                <add assembly="DevExpress.Web.ASPxTreeList.v9.1, Version=9.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5377C8E3B72B4073"/>
                <add assembly="Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91"/>
                <add assembly="Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91"/>
                <add assembly="Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91"/>
                <add assembly="Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlEnum, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91"/>
                <add assembly="Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91"/>
                <add assembly="Microsoft.VisualBasic, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>

                <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
                <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
                <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
                <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            </assemblies>
        </compilation>
        <authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms name="frmMainMenu" protection="All" loginUrl="~/LoginForm.aspx" slidingExpiration="true"/>
        </authentication>
        <pages>
            <controls>
                <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
                <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            </controls>
        </pages>
        <httpHandlers>
            <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
            <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false"/>
            <add verb="GET" path="CrystalImageHandler.aspx" type="CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalImageHandler, CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
        </httpHandlers>
        <httpModules>
            <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        </httpModules>
        <sessionState timeout="1" mode="InProc" cookieless="false"></sessionState>

        <globalization culture="en-US" uiCulture="en-US"/>
    </system.web>
    <system.codedom>
        <compilers>
            <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" warningLevel="4" type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
                <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
                <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
            </compiler>
            <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" warningLevel="4" type="Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
                <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
                <providerOption name="OptionInfer" value="true"/>
                <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
            </compiler>
        </compilers>
    </system.codedom>
    <system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
        <modules>
            <remove name="ScriptModule"/>
            <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="managedHandler" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        </modules>
        <handlers>
            <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated"/>
            <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactory"/>
            <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices"/>
            <remove name="ScriptResource"/>
            <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add name="CrystalImageHandler.aspx_GET" verb="GET" path="CrystalImageHandler.aspx" type="CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalImageHandler, CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
        </handlers>
        <defaultDocument enabled="true">
            <files>
                <remove value="index.html"/>
                <remove value="index.htm"/>
                <remove value="Default.asp"/>
                <remove value="Default.htm"/>
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="false"/>
        <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
                <add name="p3p" value="CP=&quot;IDC DSP COR CURa ADMa OUR IND PHY ONL COM STA&quot;"/>
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions.Design" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Please do not paste image, please paste the exception message exclusively

Answer (score 1):

If you see there you get an message that's says `BadImageFormatException` that is means that you have some kind of mix 32bit dll with 64bit dlls.

Check how you compile your dlls, try the AnyCPU, check also if you have include some wrong dlls, or your pool is on wrong cpu type (eg must be 32bit or not ?)

You can also read:
[MSDN BadImageFormatException Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.badimageformatexception(v=vs.110).aspx)
[BadImageFormatException Occurs When Instantiating Types Defined in a Referenced Assembly at Run-time](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/967163)

Comment: Still error. I can not find root folder in temporary ASP.NET files. Any clue? I think its not about my project solution, but others solution project (finished project which woking fine before) get same error. When I read log file (scan system file), I got System.Web.Extension.dll file corrupted.

Comment: @Slocky Please check the pool if its on correct cpu type, also check or give here the `web.config`... check if you have on web.config some other temporary folder.... you need to know in witch bit you run your app

Comment: @Slocky Do you have check if the other solution projects compile on AnyCPU ?

Comment: The pool is correct. Yes others solution project compile using AnyCPU.

Comment: @Slocky The issue is for sure some kind of mix, but how you can locate it is an other story... the web.config have many `assemblies`, do you really need to declare all ? The system.core is all ready two times...

Comment: If the problem is about kind of mix, the logic is the others solution project should working fine, right? ok, I will remove some assemblies.

Comment: @Slocky what can I say - this message is for that reason.

Comment: I have check configuration manager that the solution compile using AnyCPU. This problem make me frustated.

Comment: @Slocky Open also your iis, and see there one by one the topics, make some reset to default if necessary.